# How to prove that if $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha>0$ on an interval, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on this interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Spivak's Calculus, chapter 11 "Significance of the Derivative", problem 37:

> 37. A function $f$ is *Lipschitz of order $\alpha$* at $x$ if there is a constant $C$ such that
>
> $$(*)\ \ \ \ \ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$$
>
> for all $y$ in an interval around $x$. The function $f$ is *Lipschitz
> of order $\alpha$ on an interval* if $(*)$ holds for all $x$ and $y$
> in the interval.
>
> a) If $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha>0$ at $x$ then $f$ is
> continuous at $x$.
>
> b) If $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha>0$ on an interval, then $f$ is
> uniformly continuous on this interval.

We can prove $a)$ as follows

> Let $y=x+h$. Then $$|f(x)-f(x+h)| \leq C|h|^{\alpha}$$
>
> $\forall \epsilon>0$ if $|h|< \left ( \frac{\epsilon}{C} \right
>  )^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ then $|f(x)-f(x+h)|<\epsilon$. Therefore
> $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(x+h)=f(x)$$ Ie, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

**My question is about proving $b)$.**

The straightforward proof is

> $\forall \epsilon>0$ choose $\delta=\left ( \frac{\epsilon}{C} \right 
> > )^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$. Then for all $x$ and $y$ in an interval, we
> have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous on
> the interval.
>
> This is essentially taking the given interval and using it in the
> definition of $f$ being Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ at each point in
> the given interval.

Is it possible to have a slightly simpler proof using the following theorem (Spivak, Appendix to Chapter 8, "Uniform Continuity")?

> **Theorem 1:** $f$ continuous on $[a,b] \implies f$ uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$

Here is a slightly incomplete alternative proof for b):

> $f$ being Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ on an entire interval means it
> is Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ on each point in the interval.
>
> By a), $f$ is continuous at each point in the interval.
>
> By Theorem 1 above, if the interval is closed then $f$ is uniformly
> continuous on the interval.

**The question is, can I make this latter proof complete by extending it to all intervals, not just closed intervals? What reasoning do I need to use?**

Given an open interval, I don't think I can just take a closed interval enclosing it because I don't know if $f$ is defined in the enclosing interval.

Comment: You need the interval to be compact to ensure that any continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I do believe you can complete the proof in the way you are suggesting. However, I think it might require some heavy machinery.

Essentially, what you want is a **Lipschitz extension**, so that if $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, you can extend it to $\hat{f}:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and keep it Lipschitz. Then you will know that $\hat{f}$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, and hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$.

The classical Lipschitz extension theorem is [Kirszbraun's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem), which works in the very general setting of Hilbert spaces, of which $\mathbb{R}$ is an example. This theorem promises that you can extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ without changing the Lipschitz constant. Kirszbraun's theorem doesn't actually apply to $\alpha$-Lipschitz (sometimes called Hölder continuous) functions, but that is covered in Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1970-76-02/S0002-9904-1970-12466-1/S0002-9904-1970-12466-1.pdf).

Now, these are deep results applying to vast generalizations of this problem, and I'm sure that there are simpler proofs in this setting. Still, if you wanted to extend $f$ to an enclosing interval, it is possible!